How to ensure IntelliSense recognizes custom DLLs in OmniSharp without using .csproj in Visual Studio Code?
I'm currently working on a C# script in Visual Studio Code and using OmniSharp for code completion and IntelliSense. However, I want to reference custom DLLs directly in my scripts without having to create a .csproj file. I've tried adding the path to the DLLs in the omnisharp.json file under RoslynExtensionsOptions with the LocationPaths property, but IntelliSense still does not recognize them.
Here's what my omnisharp.json looks like:
{
  "script": {
    "enableScriptNuGetReferences": true,
    "defaultTargetFramework": "net8.0"
  },
  "RoslynExtensionsOptions": {
    "LocationPaths": [
      "./packages/WindowsInput.dll"
    ]
  }
}

`
I've verified that the DLL is in the specified location. Are there any additional configurations or steps I need to follow to make sure IntelliSense can recognize the DLLs? Also, does the systemExcludeSearchPatterns or fileOptions settings have any impact on this?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!
